SVG as a mask for PACE.JS progress bar
I'm trying to create a progress bar that utilises PACE.js to display a loading bar that will be masked with an animated SVG element, how would I go about this?
Currently I have got the animated SVG (in a g element) in a div and another div with the progress bar targeted onto it, any advice is appreciated.
enter image description here
this is my current progress, black is the svg g element, red and white is progress bar and yellow is bg
